# Average of four fields in a form

Tags: javascript

```
form.getElement('ar_essay1_read1_subscore4').bind('change', function() { 
calcEssayScore();
}).bind('keyup', function() { $(this).triggerHandler('change'); });

function calcEssayScore()
{
var score1 = form.getElement('ar_essay1_read1_subscore1').val();
var score2 = form.getElement('ar_essay1_read1_subscore2').val();
var score3 = form.getElement('ar_essay1_read1_subscore3').val();
var score4 = form.getElement('ar_essay1_read1_subscore4').val();

var recalc = ((score1 + score2 + score3 + score4) / 4);
form.getElement('sys:app:ar_essay1_read1').val(recalc.toFixed(3)); 

}
```

I know this is a total rookie javascript error, but this keeps returning errors.  If i put 4 into each field in the form, it's return 1111.000 as the sys:app:ar_essay1_read1 score.  How should I be structuring the formula to make it work correctly?

Comment: Java is to JavaScript what Car is to Carpet

Comment: you're correct.. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `parseInt(val, 10)` or `parseFloat(val)` to convert the value of each form field as number. Otherwise, you are just doing string manipulation.

Comment: Or [unary +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28.2B%29)